# SMS handling with regards to Priority settings and Ordered vs. Unordered Broadcast

Tags: java, android, sms, telephony

I'd like to ask questions related to handling of android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED.

Q:

> Is android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED an ordered or non-ordered
>   broadcast? Where is the official documentation to identify whether is
>   a non-ordered or ordered broadcast?

```
<receiver android:name="com.nttdocomo.android.msg.chats.SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Q:

> With reference to the above code where the priority is set to "10". Is
>   it possible for another SMS app to hijack my app, by setting to "11"
>   or any higher value, to change the SMS message context or even delete
>   it so it would never reach my app?

Q:

> if I set to highest possible priority - ie.
>   'android:priority="2147483647" ' - and what happens if yet another app
>   also set to the same highest priority "2147483647"?

Thanks!

Comment: Before KitKat (4.4, API level 19), it was an ordered broadcast, and apps could intercept and abort it before others got it, by upping their own priority. Since KitKat, it doesn't matter, because the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast can no longer be aborted. Every app registered for it will get it.

Comment: @Mike M. Any link to reference documentation that it is no longer an ordered broadcast since API 19? (I'd like to read it to understand more.)

Comment: That's not really what I said, though I may not have phrased it well. It may very well still be an ordered broadcast, and the last time I went digging through the source, it was, but that was around Lollipop's release. Stuff like that isn't in the documentation anywhere, AFAIK, but the blog page they put up when KitKat came out explains that the `SMS_RECEIVED` can't be aborted anymore, which is why the ordered/priority stuff isn't really a concern these days. [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)